# refresh contenturl in add-on sdk

Tags: javascript, firefox, sdk, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How can i refresh the Panel with the contenturl when i click in the widget icon? my code is simple here it's:

```
    var data = require("sdk/self").data;

exports.main = function() {
    var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
        width: 400,
        height: 560, 
        contentURL: "http://sample.com/index.html",      
    });

    panel.on("show", function() {
      panel.port.emit("show");
    });

    require("sdk/widget").Widget({
        id: "Sample",
        label: "Sample",
        contentURL: data.url("icon128.png"),
        panel:panel
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the panel's `contentURL` on widget click like so:

```
require("sdk/widget").Widget({
    id: "Sample",
    label: "Sample",
    contentURL: data.url("icon128.png"),
    panel:panel,
    onClick: function() {
      panel.contentURL = contentURL;
    }
});
```

---

Keep in mind the below

[Widget docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/widget):

> *The widget API is deprecated from Firefox 29 onwards. Please see the ui module for replacements. In particular, for a simple button, try the [action button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui#ActionButton) or [toggle button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui#ToggleButton) APIs.*

[Panel docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Attaching_panels_to_buttons):

> You can attach a panel to a toggle button by passing the button itself as the position option to the panel's show() method or to its constructor:

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var button = ToggleButton({
  id: "my-button",
  label: "my button",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html"),
  onHide: handleHide
});

function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });
  }
}

function handleHide() {
  button.state('window', {checked: false});
}
```